# Checking If-Match header etag against model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, concurrency, etag

I want to implement a concurrency safe check when doing PUT / PATCH within my API. I can place an etag in the server response that represents the hash of a given resource. What I'm struggling to understand is where within the Laravel architecture I can verify the client provided hash against the model to be updated / replaced.

I've considered a route middleware but the model is not resolved at this point so I can't get the model hash. If I did resolve the model in the middleware then there will be a performance overhead as the route will then also resolve the model (double the work for the api). At least I think the model is not resolved, is there a way to get the resolved model and pass onto the route so that it doesn't need to resolve it (again)?

I've also considered a policy applied to the route, this initially seemed perfect as it receives the resolved model that the user is intending to put / patch, but I can only return a true / false here. As such the response would be a 403 forbidden (if the resource state has changed before the update / replace request was made) and I can't seen to override this with a 412 Precondition Failed response. I could override the exception within Handler.php, but then any 'real' 403 responses would also get overridden.

What I don't want to have to do is implement this within the controller methods, that seems like a brute force solution. Can anybody suggest a nice generic 'Laravel way' solution?

Many thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Took a look at model events, it looks like the you can stop the propagation of an event by returning false within the listener handler, though I don't think this will stop the underlying action that distatched the event. Does anybody know if this really is the case?

I also looked at model observers, though there is nothing in the docs about canceling the event, this article (https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/cancelling-a-model-save-update-delete-through-events) indicates that you can. If so this would be ideal, except that I can't see how (in the model) to understand that the save has been cancelled and return a correct error message to the client?

Answer (score 1):

Model events might be the place do to it.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    /**
     * Check model hash vs header etag
     */
    static::updating(function (Model $model) {
         $etag = request()->header('etag');
         // check $etag against model hash, return false to prevent update
    });
}
```

You could make a nice generic solution this way with a `BaseModel` and a common hash check method.

**Update**

As I understand event propagation, once you return false from a listener that's the end of it's lifecycle. Subsequent listeners will not receive the event.

> Sometimes, you may wish to stop the propagation of an event to other
>   listeners. You may do so by returning false from your listener's
>   handle method.

What transport method are you using, if any currently, to return a message to the user? WebSocket via Echo? Echo would be an easy way to do so, broadcasting a notification back to an authenticated user on a private channel is made trivial(ish) with [Laravel Echo Server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server).

I'd approach it by dispatching back right out of the model event closure:

```
static::updating(function (Model $model) {
     $etag = request()->header('etag');
     // check $etag against model hash, return false to prevent update
     if ($failedCheck) dispatch(NotifyUserOfUpdateFailure::class, $model);
     else doUpdate()
});
```

**Edit**

I think this should be possible in a single middleware alone. Because we have access to the `route()` helper we can pull request parameters out and query for the model in middleware.

```
namespace VdPoel\src\Http\Middleware;

// say we have a Vehicle resource, with a base endpoint /api/vehicles.
//
// PUT or PATCH
// consider this url path is a valid api endpoint
// /api/vehicles/1
// defined some routes for 'vehicle' records using resource routes
// Route::resource('vehicles', 'VehicleController');
// or standard route definitions
// Route::put('/vehicles/{vehicle}', 'VehicleController@update')->middleware(CheckHash::class);
// Route::patch('/vehicles/{vehicle}', 'VehicleController@update')->middleware(CheckHash::class);

class CheckHash
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|null
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        if (!in_array($request->method(), ['PUT', 'PATCH'])) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $hash = $request->header('e-tag');
        $vehicleId = $request->route()->parameter('vehicle');

        if ($vehicle = Vehicle::find($vehicleId)) {
            return $vehicle->getETagHash() === $hash ? $next($request) : abort(412, 'Hash does not match');
        }

        abort(404, 'Vehicle not found');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll take a look and update on this. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Took a look at model events, Please see my update in the question and let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: Updated my answer with my immediate thoughts.

Comment: Thanks. This is just a JSON API, as such the Response should be updated with the correct error code (412) and the PUT / PATCH will not have taken place. That's why I thought a middleware would be great as I could update the response, but I don't have the resolved model from the route at this point (I think). The first answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022367/best-way-of-passing-response-information-from-model-to-controller-using-laravel) seems to be what I need to do, but I would still need to add the logic to return the error in each controller and affected method, not good!

Comment: Yeah I don't think events will suit your needs in this case. What about After Middleware? It might be really impactful on your code, but maybe you could run the request as simply a check to see if it's safe to update, then as the response is coming back through the middleware pipeline, do or don't perform the update based on the response. So after `$response = $next($request);` in a middleware.

Comment: There are a number of packages available for etags, I imagine you've already searched through them but just in case https://github.com/matthewbdaly/laravel-etag-middleware... Edit: That's actually only checking GET requests, wouldn't be useful in your case..

Comment: Yes, spotted that one and will use for sending the etag to the client. RE your suggestion about After Middleware - I'm guessing I still won't have access to the resolved model to actually process the update, It also feels like I'd just be rebuilding controller functionality in the middleware - perhaps I'm not understanding your suggestion? Apologies, very new to LAravel, so still feeling my way around.

Comment: I've been thinking about this than I should be at work, hah. Have a look at my latest edit. Model resolution shouldn't be an issue at any point within the middleware pipeline so long as we can access the request and route objects. I've done created some somewhat similar middleware for roles and various authentication checks, those need Model access.

Comment: Your help is appreciated. What you've suggested roughly fits my initial thoughts. My concern with this solution was that I'd have to manually resolve the model, which would then be resolved again by the route if the middleware passes. This would have a performance hit, but perhaps this performance hit would be better than having lots of controller calls to a resource to do this. Also, I could pass in the model and parameter to 'guard' with the middleware definition on the route. Thanks for your help.